# How to connect points intervened by NA in ggplot in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the following data, the y-values are intervened by NA values. When I try to plot the values in ggplot with the following codes, values intervened by NA are not connected. How to connect them?

My data are

```
> dput(dat)
structure(list(iso2c = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", ""), country = c("Chile", "Chile", "Chile", "Chile", 
"Chile", "Chile", "Chile", "Chile", "Chile", "Chile", "Chile", 
"Chile", "Chile", "Chile", "Chile", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", 
"Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", 
"Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Uruguay", 
"Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", 
"Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", "Uruguay", 
"Uruguay", "Uruguay"), gini = structure(c(NA, 0.504536343101375, 
NA, 0.508405328631639, NA, 0.519976764499864, NA, NA, 0.517926578610535, 
NA, NA, 0.546104633218656, NA, NA, 0.555941876065133, 0.491403873718798, 
NA, 0.493552378351658, NA, 0.475493191921101, NA, 0.505257097450159, 
NA, 0.497832261107211, 0.511129547580954, 0.509540976787275, 
NA, 0.512466806741829, NA, 0.539429975768021, 0.41795824834724, 
0.420833068910888, 0.41522929739879, 0.435913025490141, 0.454821576286135, 
0.46476558158648, 0.464685756891657, 0.47909997120289, 0.473975286071775, 
0.458674509620144, 0.471347484288568, 0.462187124859573, 0.46655236747263, 
0.461672318705308, 0.443881977304363), label = "Gini Coefficient"), 
    year = c(2014L, 2013L, 2012L, 2011L, 2010L, 2009L, 2008L, 
    2007L, 2006L, 2005L, 2004L, 2003L, 2002L, 2001L, 2000L, 2014L, 
    2013L, 2012L, 2011L, 2010L, 2009L, 2008L, 2007L, 2006L, 2005L, 
    2004L, 2003L, 2002L, 2001L, 2000L, 2014L, 2013L, 2012L, 2011L, 
    2010L, 2009L, 2008L, 2007L, 2006L, 2005L, 2004L, 2003L, 2002L, 
    2001L, 2000L)), row.names = c(NA, 45L), class = "data.frame")
```

The codes used are

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = year, y = gini, colour = country)) +
geom_line() +
geom_point(aes(shape = country), size=3)+
scale_shape_manual(values=c(1:3))
```

The plot I get is

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to drop the missing values from the data frame. Use is.na() function to filter rows where gini is not NA.

```
    df_nona <- dat[!is.na(dat$gini),]
    ggplot(df_nona, aes(x = year, y = gini, colour = country)) +
             geom_line() +
             geom_point(aes(shape = country), size=3)+
             scale_shape_manual(values=c(1:3))
```

Output:
[image: Dropped NA values to connect line]